# Support directory is missing: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/

Tags: maven

My project is stuck in the Gradle Download phase.

It stucks when downloading the following:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/maven-metadata.xml

I see that "Support" is missing:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android

This started happening on Feb 7 2018.  It was working perfectly before that.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following line from the build.gradle file:

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'

I guess I can download the same library from somewhere else.
I don't need it anyways.